# Book where girl is hurt by tree with magical powers

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone know the name of the book in which someone (I think a girl) is hurt by a tree with magic powers near the very beginning of the book? I thought it might be *The Sword of Shannara*, but there is not such a scene at the beginning of this book. Could it be another book in the *Shannara* series?

Comment: Could you add some more details? Right now this might be a bit too general.

Comment: Is the tree a Whomping Willow? I know a series of books that had that...

Comment: Could also be a tangle-tree from Xanth.

Comment: What is the name of the series with the Whomping Willow?

Comment: *Harry Potter*, unfortunately.

Comment: I was wondering if you were referring to Harry Potter.   No, that's not it.

Comment: This is my first time using this site, so still trying to figure it out. Did a user named Valorum edit my post?

Comment: @Sarah yes, Valorum edited your post. If you click on the words "edited yesterday" you can see what the changes were. This is useful as you can see how to improve future questions too.

Comment: Do you remember anything of what the tree's abilities were, how she was hurt? Did it have tentacles? The ability to breath fire? The ability to suck her youth from her? Razor-sharp leaves?

Comment: If I remember correctly, she was made unconscious or somewhat unconscious. But I don’t think this happened as a result of a physical injury (like being burned by fire or cut by sharp leaves).

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be referring to the sequel to *The Sword of Shannara*, which is *The Elfstones of Shannara*. If I recall correctly, near the beginning a female character interacts telepathically with a tree called the Ellcrys, and it renders her unconscious.

Comment: Could you add a quote for support?

Comment: The character who interacts with the tree is called Lauren, but Lauren is a boy (elf) not a girl and he doesn't become unconcious.

Comment: Ah, I must have misremembered, then.